# C++ command line argument for .exe program

Tags: c++, command-line, arguments

I have `program.exe` that is being created on my Windows machine. For some reason I am not able to pass in command line arguments properly.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
  ///////testing
  cout << "\n\n(int)ARGV[1]: " << (int)argv[1] << "\n\n";

  return 0;
}
```

In terminal I run:

```
program.exe 4
```

I see `(int)ARGV[1]: 15333464` printed to my console.

Why does this happen, and how I can modify the code? I should get the number 4 printed out.

Comment: Why the immediate downvote? This isn't super clear cut to me and I couldn't find the exact question..

Comment: You cannot simply cast from a `char*` pointer to `int`.

Comment: Can you show me how to properly get my `int`? I'm very rusty with C/C++.

Comment: `argv[1]` is a pointer, which is being c-style cast to an `int`.

Comment: you must use `atoi(argv[1])`

Comment: Ok thanks guys. If somebody wants to formally answer I'd be happy to upvote and accept.

Comment: [`[c++]converting char* to int`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%2b%2b%5dconverting%20char*%20to%20int)

Comment: @JDS Well, there are many more answers besides `atoi()`.

Answer (score 8):

When you cast from `char*` to `int` you get the pointer value bitpattern interpreted as an integer.

A good way to instead interpret the character string pointed to, as a specification of an integer, is to use `std::stoi` from the `<string>` header.

Thus:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>    // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string>      // std::stoi
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cout << "ARGV[1]: " << stoi( argv[1] ) << "\n";
}
```

For the case where the argument isn't a valid specification of an integer, `stoi` will throw an exception, and in the code above that will cause the program to terminate with some message displayed – a crash. That's generally preferable to producing incorrect results. But if you want to handle it, read up on `try` and `catch` in your C++ textbook.

---

If you want *filenames* as command line arguments, and more generally filesystem paths, then do note that the Windows convention for encoding of `char` based strings is Windows ANSI, which has a very limited set of characters. Some filenames and paths on my Norwegian computer can't be represented in your Windows ANSI (yes, Windows ANSI is locale-specific). So for this the C and C++ `main` argument mechanism, is ungood.

The Windows API provides a pair of `wchar_t` based functions that can be used as a (working) alternative, namely `GetCommandLine` (retrieves the raw UTF-16-encoded command line) and `CommandLineToArgvW` (standard parsing to produce individual arguments).

Some Windows compilers also provide an alternative to standard `main` called `wmain`, where `argv` is declared as `wchar_t* argv[]`. These compilers include Visual C++ and the MinGW64 variant of g++.

Answer (score 0):

Here `argv[1]` is a character pointer (`char*`) so you cant convert a character pointer to an integer by type casting. So to convert the character pointer to an integer use the `atoi()` function, which is available in the c standard library (include the `cstdlib` library).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::atoi;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << atoi(argv[1]) << " " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `atoi()` returns zero if the argument passed to it cannot be converted to an integer. So you could check the returned value and if it is zero then print the relevant message.

Thus:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using std::atoi;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::strcmp;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 2)
    {
        if(atoi(argv[1]) == 0 && strcmp(argv[1], "0") != 0)
            cout << "The argument supplied is not an integer" << endl;
        else
            cout << atoi(argv[1]) << " " << endl;
    }
    else if( argc > 2)
        cout << "Too many arguements" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Insufficient arguements" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if parameter is "00" or "-0" ?